# Container engine cluster version 1.1.7 nodes unavailable

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Yesterday I recreated a cluster so that it has version 1.1.7 for both master and nodes. After deploying a first service there it's no longer operational as it should be.

I can't ssh into the nodes. Deployments fail with a FailedScheduling error. The Kube UI fails with the following response.

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kube-ui\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

Resetting the nodes doesn't help here. Any ideas to what could cause this?

Comment: Resetting actually did seem to help, but it seems to defeat the purpose of kubernetes to have to do that yourself.

Comment: That error means that the kube-ui pod isn't running in your cluster. Can you run `kubectl get pods --all-nampespaces` to see whether it is pending or it doesn't exist at all?

Comment: Hi @RobertBailey, running `kubectl get ev --namespace=kube-system` we can see this message from the **l7-lb-controller-e8hoy** pod:

`Liveness probe failed: Cluster unhealthy: Get https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/global/backendServices?alt=json: oauth2/google: can't get a token from the metadata service; not running on GCE`

That **no running on GCE** is suspicious... we used Terraform with google_container_cluster to generate the cluster, we did it in the past an it was working fine. So not sure where is the problem coming from.... any clue?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering what was the cause of the issue, we added more VMs to the cluster and setup resource request/limit on each pod to prevent the whole cluster to run out of resources. This seems to solve it.
Alex, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the cluster's nodes are all unhealthy. That would explain there being no kube-ui pod running, and the scheduling errors. Not being able to SSH into them is incredibly strange.

What does `kubectl get nodes` and `kubectl get node NODENAME -o yaml` (swapping out NODENAME for one of the names of the nodes) return?

Comment: Also, if you don't mind sharing your project ID and/or the name of your cluster, I'm happy to help figure out what's happening with the nodes. You can reach me using arob at google.com

Comment: Thanks, we will contact you.
`conditions:
  - lastHeartbeatTime: 2016-02-11T10:18:36Z
    lastTransitionTime: 2016-02-11T10:11:00Z
    message: kubelet has sufficient disk space available
    reason: KubeletHasSufficientDisk
    status: "False"
    type: OutOfDisk
  - lastHeartbeatTime: 2016-02-11T10:18:36Z
    lastTransitionTime: 2016-02-11T10:19:21Z
    message: Kubelet stopped posting node status.
    reason: NodeStatusUnknown
    status: Unknown
    type: Ready`